# Connect two boards together after removing Screw Terminals

Tags: power, voltage, pcb

An adapter board (to a card edge connector like PCI Express x1) is needed to be designed to for the breakout board below. This should involve replacing the board's screw terminals with some male rectangle connectors, with will be soldered to the adapter board as well.

However it seems that the screw terminal have a pitch of 3.5mm, but no rectangle connectors with a pitch of 3.5mm can be found (at least [on Digi key](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-board-to-board-connectors-headers-male-pins/1442672)). Do such connectors exists, or is there a better way to make the connections?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply include the circuitry of this board into your PCIe board, rather than trying to connect the two boards together?

Comment: @DaveTweed I dont have enough space on the main board to include several of these breakout boards, so I have to mount these boards perpendicular to it. Is this a sane way to do it?

Comment: It's impossible to say without knowing something about the physical configuration of the system. It's hard to imagine a PCIe slot that would have room for perpendicular boards. How do you plan to support them mechanically, and how do you intend to bring out the thermocouple connections?

Comment: @DaveTweed Thinking of using the PCIe slot itself as the mechanical support. The device wont move around so that should be sufficient I suppose. The thermocouple measurements are taken from the screw terminals, so I intend to replace the screw terminals with some kind of edge connector, connect the edge connector to a PCIe slot on a board, route the connections to the pins of an Arduino via a board stack ontop of the Arduino. So like: Thermocouple board -> (via PCIe slot) -> Stacked board's pins -> Arduino pins

Answer (score 1):

Phoenix contact manufactures board-to-board connectors that use 3.5mm pitch, they're actually quite common. It's a bit bulkier than the header strip, but it will work, take a look at this:

[Phoenix Contact - Product list - Headers (press in)](http://goo.gl/rizRcg)

Also, check Farnell and Mouser if they are available in your country, you'll definitely find something that suits your needs.